# PHP to split array of objects with title in array

Tags: php, json

I have an array of objects like below:

```
[
    {
        "TYPE": "food",
        "NAME": "abc"
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "fruit",
        "NAME": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "food",
        "NAME": "def"
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "food",
        "NAME": "ghi"
    },
]
```

How can I split this array of objects into multiple arrays such that the desired output looks like:

```
[
    {
        "TYPE": "food",
        "ITEMS": 
        [
            {
                "TYPE": "food",
                "NAME": "abc"
            },
            {
                "TYPE": "food",
                "NAME": "def"
            },
            {
                "TYPE": "food",
                "NAME": "ghi"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "fruit",
        "ITEMS": 
        [
            {
                "TYPE": "fruit",
                "NAME": "xyz"
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Note that the parent object has its own identifier (TYPE)

I tried this:

```
    $result = [];
    foreach ($DT_DATA as $key => $value) {
        $group = $value->TYPE;
        if (!isset($result[$group])) {
            $result[$group] = [];
        }

        $result[$group][] = $value;
    }
    $result = array_values($result);
```

But the parent group does not contain "TYPE" and also "ITEMS" array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some improvements that will do the job:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($DT_DATA as $key => $value) {
    $group = $value->TYPE;
    if (!isset($result[$group])) {
        // init with array of required structure
        $result[$group] = [
            'TYPE' => $group,
            'ITEMS' => [],
        ];
    }

    // add $value to `ITEMS` subarray
    $result[$group]['ITEMS'][] = $value;
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Any idea how I can split into a third level with a different key? say, the third key 'COLOR'. Meaning it would be TYPE > COLOR > `{TYPE: "FRUIT", NAME: "xyz", COLOR: "RED"}`

Comment: Add to `ITEMS` under key `COLOR`? But it's better to ask new question with related data provided.